# SpringMvc with Jpa and Junit Integration

Tags: java, spring, jpa, junit

My sample code at [here](https://github.com/catinred2/springmvcjunit)

When try to run junit test, got these error message.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'nameDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.test.entity.po.NamePO
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.test.entity.po.NamePO

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see in your code :

```
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService{ 
@Autowired 
private NameDao testDao;
```

A setter method for testDao is missing.The exception is :

> Error creating bean with name 'nameDao': Invocation of init method
>   failed

I think that the @autowired service can't be injected.

Comment: no it didn't help. the exception is "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.test.entity.po.NamePO"

Answer (score 0):

just remove the persistence.xml and add packagesToScan property to entityManager. the junit test will be ok. I've update the code in github.